# Cannot select Object in 3D View

Tags: 3d-view

I have an object that I cannot select nor manipulate. I can get into Edit Mode by using the Outliner however it is useless since I cannot Move it as an object. Seperating, duplicating etc the selection in edit mode doesn't do anything either.

See for yourself:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your Gif is cropped in a way that might obscure the answer. When you select the visible objects there is an eye we can see. Next to the eye should be an arrow/cursor & a camera symbol. If the arrow/cursor is grey you have restricted selection. Just click it again to make it active.

Comment: Please provide your .blend file to be able to help you

Comment: You image is unreachable, please use the builtin image upload tool in the toolbar while editing your question next time.

Comment: Stackexchange doesn't allow me to upload gifs. I added 2 screenshots. No the object is not hidden. H and alt H dont solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the icon that looks like an arrow next to the eye on the outliner?

[image]

If that icon is ghosted the object cannot be selected. Click on the icon to enable it

These icons are switches:

The Eye icon is to toggle object visibility on the 3D viewport.

The **Arrow** Icon toggles selectability.

The Camera Icon toggles rendering.

Please take a moment to read more on the Blender Manual

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html?highlight=object%20level#toggling-object-level-restrictions